# how to get specific parameters in a square bracket and store it in to a specific variable in tcl

Tags: tcl

```
set_dont_use [get_lib_cells */*CKGT*0P*] -power
set_dont_use [get_lib_cells */*CKTT*0P*] -setup
```

The above is a text file.

I Want to store */*CKGT*OP* and */*CKTT*OP* in to a variable this is the programme which a person helped me with

```
set f [open theScript.tcl]
# Even with 10 million lines, modern computers will chew through it rapidly
set lines [split [read $f] "\n"]
close $f

# This RE will match the sample lines you've told us about; it might need tuning
# for other inputs (and knowing what's best is part of the art of RE writing)
set RE {^set_dont_use \[get_lib_cells ([\w*/]+)\] -\w+$}

foreach line $lines {
    if {[regexp $RE $line -> term]} {
        # At this point, the part you want is assigned to $term
        puts "FOUND: $term"
    }
}
```

My question is if more than one cells like for example

```
set_dont_use [get_lib_cells */*CKGT*0P* */*CKOU*TR* /*....] -power
set_dont_use [get_lib_cells */*CKGT*WP* */*CKOU*LR* /*....] -setup
```

then the above script isn't helping me to store the these "n" number cells in the variable known as term

Could any of u people help me 
Thanking you ahead in time

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to grep parameters inside square brackets?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42143073/how-to-grep-parameters-inside-square-brackets)

Comment: This is the same question you have asked already. If you want to clarify something, you can edit the original question.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with

```
proc get_lib_cells args {
    global term
    lappend term {*}$args
}

proc unknown args {}
```

and then just

```
source theScript.tcl
```

in a shell that doesn't have the module you are using loaded, and thus doesn't know any of these non-standard commands.

By setting `unknown` to do nothing, other commands in the script will just be passed over.

Note that redefining `unknown`impairs Tcl's ability to automatically load some processes, so don't keep using that interpreter after this.

Documentation:
[global](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/global.htm),
[lappend](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lappend.htm),
[proc](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/proc.htm),
[unknown](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/unknown.htm),
[{*} (syntax)](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/Tcl.htm)

Comment: Could you explain what the benefit of defining `unknown` is?

Comment: i am still not clear with the code peter could u just explain it.. Thanks

Comment: @KarthikKumar: I've added a bit of explanation now.

Comment: hi @PeterLewerin get_lib_cells is a predefined proc so we cant use it can u please some other way...Thank u for the effort

Comment: @KarthikKumar: it's not defined if you use a shell that hasn't loaded the module for it.

Answer (score 0):

Your coding seems like the Synopsys syntax, meaning - it shouldn't work the way you wrote it, I'd expect curly braces:
`set_dont_use [get_lib_cells {*/*CKGT*0P* */*CKOU*TR* /*....}] -power`
moreover, the `\w` doesn't catch the *,/ (see [this](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TclCmd/re_syntax.htm)).
If I were you, I'd go for `set RE {^set_dont_use \[get_lib_cells \{?([\S*]+ )+\}?\] -\w+$}` and treat the resulting pattern match as a list.

**Edit:**
see this:
% regexp {^set_dont_use [get_lib_cells {?(\S+) ?}?]} $line -> match
1
% echo $match
*/*CKGT*0P*
If you have more than one item in your line, add another parentheses inside the curly braces:
`regexp {^set_dont_use \[get_lib_cells \{?(\S+) ?(\S+)?\}?\]} $l -> m1 m2`
ect.
**Another Edit**
take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3369458/how-do-i-extract-all-matches-with-a-tcl-regex), just in case you want multiple matches with the same single pattern, but than, instead of \S+, you should try something that looks like this: `[A-Za-z\/\*]`

Comment: couldn't compile regular expression pattern: invalid escape \ sequence
    while executing
"regexp $RE $line -> term"
    ("foreach" body line 2)
    invoked from within
"foreach line $lines {
   if {[regexp $RE $line -> term]} {
      # At this point, the part you want is assigned to $term
     puts "FOUND: $term"
    ..."
    (file "con.tcl" line 10)
This is the following error i am getting while excecuting the sciprt given by u

Comment: here the number of cells is defined by the tool, suppose we have more than 1K cells it will be practically impossible to keep adding parentheses rit  please correct me if i am wrong